# Debian server changing ip address

Tags: networking, debian, ip-address

I had set up a Debian server with an ip address that was assigned to another device by accident. I forced the server to connect through /etc/network/interfaces but am still finding it switches to the original ip address and I am unable to find the original network configuration file.
The interim fix is to change the /etc/network/interfaces to its original device of ens192 but the device is currently eth0, and change it back to its current device and reboot.

Comment: So, what's your `ip addr` output, what's the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` and, importantly, does any *DHCP client* currently running (you can check that with something like `ps axu | grep dhcp`, but it is possible to miss something, as I don't guarantee that any software capable to be a DHCP client always had `dhcp` in its command line)?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov It has one dhcp client running.

Comment: Are you sure it is needed? Check its logs; maybe it is installing a rogue IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your network interfaces file is configured to use a static IP address. Change the configuration to use DHCP to get you back to a working solution then start from scratch with what you were trying to achieve.